# iTunes 9 not sorting albums by track order consistently

Tags: media, libraries, sorting, itunes

I have my iTunes library set to sort by music by Artist, then album [image]. For most of my albums this will also sort the albums in the correct track listing order (using the track number tag).

Except for one album:

[image]

As you can see, "The Boy Who Knew Too Much" seems to sort erratically. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Moreover, Grace Kelly (Acoustic) appears first in Life In Cartoon Motion album, though its track number is 12.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all the tags that should match actually do match for all the files in the album (Artist, Album Artist, Year, etc...). Select the whole album then Get Info to set tags for multiple tracks.

I would start by setting the Album Artist to Mika (for the example you've given, obviously) if it isn't already.

I notice in Life In Cartoon Motion, Grace Kelly (Acoustic) is set as 12 of 14 and Over My Shoulder [Hidden Track] is set as 12. Things like this could be causing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem with the latest version (9.1.1.12) - was that the Disc n of n was not filled in for all tracks.

Selected all tracks, Get Info and then entered Disc 1 of 1 and saved, fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution to this problem is to check whether there is anything entered into the 'Album Artist' field on the tracks that appear to not be sorting properly in an album. This can mess with your sorting, and and you might not have "Album Artist' selected for viewing in your iTunes library view. So the simplest way to check this is the case is to:

1. select your album
2. click *Get Info*
3. click the tick box next to album artist
4. click *OK*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing something like this so something is really strange. Maybe it's because they are formatted as "x out of y"? What happens if you just change to just "x" instead?

Comment: Have the track listings both ways, and it sorts fine for all of them. There does not seen to be a clear difference between this and other albums

Comment: Very weird indeed.